# Getting Cobertura to dump from Jboss AS 7

Tags: jboss7.x, cobertura

I am trying to Obtain Cobertura Code Coverage reports for a Jboss AS 7 Application.
I have properly Instrumented the app java artefacts and they all deploy fine.
But I am not able to get Cobertura to dump the Cobertura.ser report upon stopping the AS.
As mentioned in the Cobertura FAQ I have started the AS with -Djboss.shutdown.forceHalt=false but this has no effect. Any Clues what could be done ... I have different test suites that I want to generate coverage reports so stopping the AS is my best option to dump the Cobertura.ser from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have troubles updating the run.bat file in your jboss-setup/bin folder,
can you replace the line

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000
```

of run.bat file with the below line

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.shutdown.forceHalt=false -Dnet.sourceforge.cobertura.datafile="%JBOSS_HOME%\bin\cobertura.ser"
```

I have assumed that 'cobertura.ser' is placed in your jboss-setup/bin folder.

Comment: Many thanks for your response @revrevistar. However I have tried with additionally specifying the path to the cobertura.ser as you have indicated. But it has no effect! Still no output from Cobertura.